# table-lookup directive can not find an existing table where preparing data

Tags: cdap

Hi: I am new to use CDAP(Cask™ Data Application Platform).

I have parsed the states.json file and successfully wrote the CDAP Table Dataset named "StateTableDataset1".

When I execute table-lookup state StateTableDataset1 in the customer tab, an exception occurs. The exception information is: io.cdap.directives.lookup.TableLookup@3031fd7b : Please check that a dataset 'StateTableDataset1' of type Table exists.

Screenshot of the StateTableDataset1 dataset:

```
Start time  SQL query   Status  Actions
08-22-2019 05:21:35 PM  SELECT * FROM default.dataset_statetabledataset1 LIMIT 500  FINISHED    
name    abbreviation
Alabama AL
Alaska  AK
American Samoa  AS
Arizona AZ
Arkansas    AR
```

May I ask if I have omitted any steps, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same issue ;-) and got reply back from the Google group CDAP User community stating that this is an issue with CDAP 6.0 here is the bug with [reason](https://issues.cask.co/browse/CDAP-15584) on why you see this issue. As a workaround you can create a custom [UDD](https://github.com/data-integrations/example-directive) with [tablelookup](https://github.com/data-integrations/wrangler/blob/develop/wrangler-core/src/main/java/io/cdap/directives/lookup/TableLookup.java)

Comment: reference -> https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!topic/cdap-user/B1KBKPAIXaI

Comment: thanks, I use version of 5.1.2 and the probleam solved.